# Homeomorphism between the Euclidean and a "modified" Euclidean topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The topology of Euclidean space is defined by the Euclidean metric, which in turn is derived from the set of real numbers. Furthermore, the real numbers are defined via Dedekind cuts of the rational numbers. My question is: if one were to define an alternative set of "rational numbers" (i.e. a set of rational expressions with irrational numerators/denominators) from which to derive the real numbers via the Dedekind approach, could one ensure that the resulting topology would be homeomorphic to the usual one?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of "alternative rational numbers" you want. It should be a field, such that the Dedekind approach makes sense.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why a field would be a requirement for that approach?

Comment: From the construction:"Establishing the ordered field of rational numbers is the prerequisite for the actual set we are aiming for: the complete ordered field of real numbers".

Comment: I see. So, if the set were merely densely ordered but not a field, would that prevent any hope of recovering the reals?

Comment: Recovering the reals would also mean recovering the subfield of rational numbers, in some or other way. It is not clear to me how you will obtain the real numbers by Dedekind cuts if you start from something else than $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that if the set were countable, densely and totally ordered with no upper or lower bound, then it must be order-isomorphic to the rational numbers and therefore must result in the same topology?

Answer (score 1):

In response to the comments: [Cantor proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order#Uniqueness) that any two countable dense linear orders without endpoints are order-isomorphic. In particular, they have isomorphic Dedekind completions (where the Dedekind completion of a linear order $L$ is the set of nonempty proper initial segments of $L$ ordered by inclusion). So as clarified by the comments the answer to your question is **yes**.

- Incidentally, it's worth noting that more complicated things happen when we look at *uncountable* linear orders. For example, since $\mathbb{R}$ is second-countable the linear order $\omega_1$ does not order-embed into $\mathbb{R}$ (even if $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ is much larger than $\aleph_1$). See also the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/315526/8133).